How to set the time so that it lags by 1 second
I need the time to lag exactly by 1 second. That is, so that the time is synchronized, but lags.
Now I use timedatectl set-ntp on.
How can this be achieved? Maybe there is a possibility to set the time zone to -1sec?

Do you really need the actual time to be 1 second off? or just display time with a second off? (an exemple of the later, with 3 secondes for easier comparisons:  date ; date -d "now - 3 seconds"). you can also add "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%::z" to have both dates displayed in the correct time format : date -d "now - 1 second" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%::z"

It is the time that should be different.
A program that is oriented towards the system time should start its processes a second later.

Can you use LD_PRELOAD to replace the time() function with one that subtracts a second from the real time? Maybe easier would be to define your own timezone.
